# Is my computer powerful enough?

Tags: ros, cpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

My team is constructing an underwater glider that is going to be controlled by a PC104 computer. It is going to have to control/read from servos, pressure sensors, orientation sensors, and such while computing the all the autopilot information. This computer has a 500MHz processor and 256MB of DDR DRAM. Will it be powerful enough to run everything? It is having troubles with the turtle simulation in the tutorial; especially the mimicking turtle...

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10696/is-my-computer-powerful-enough?/) by [jamethy](https://answers.ros.org/users/874/jamethy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-07-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jamethy](https://answers.ros.org/users/874/jamethy/) on 2011-07-25**:
PS Thanks for answering and so quickly!

**Comment by [jamethy](https://answers.ros.org/users/874/jamethy/) on 2011-07-25**:
Also, I didn't think about the removal of the GUI during operation (I guess I need to get though the tutorial!). I'm sure this will improve performance. I just wanted to make sure that ROS is a good choice for us before we put all our effort into it, as we are set using the PC104.

**Comment by [jamethy](https://answers.ros.org/users/874/jamethy/) on 2011-07-25**:
The autopilot system isn't really set in stone as of yet, but eventually this glider will be set loose in a large lake for a couple of days and it needs to be able to know it's position and stay on a course (which we will presumably set).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-23**:
I think you need to elaborate what you want to do algorithmically. As for the turtle: This should be a very simple example, but I guess you ran the GUI with it that was taking all the performance.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-07-22**:
Sounds like a Geode LX800 board to me. I can recommend using a small Atom based board (for example FitPC2) instead. We did that on our KidSize humanoid robots 2 years ago and are quite happy with the improved performance. FitPC2 definitely works well with ROS.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-22**:
Could you elaborate on "computing the all the autopilot information"? Do you need full 3D (6dof) navigation support w/ obstacle avoidance? Just, say, keep the glider going "straight and level"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

closing this question as it has not had activity in over a month

In general, this question is not answerable by the community, as you are the expert on the your own software needs.  It is possible to use ROS w/o adding significant overhead to what you are doing, so it is likely that your own software will be the bottleneck.  i.e. if your system can run Linux, it can run ROS.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0